# Geometric shape manipulation for Direct2D

Tags: c++, mfc, directx, shapes, direct2d

I have an application using `Direct2D` with `MFC` support.
I am able to show images and graphics, using `MFC` API:

```
CRenderTarget::DrawRectangle(const CD2DRectF& rect, CD2DBrush* pBrush, FLOAT fStrokeWidth = 1.0, ID2D1StrokeStyle* strokeStyle = NULL)
```

Now I would like to manipulate those shapes, like moving, rotating, rescaling.
I have implemented something for rectangles, drawing handles to select, scale and move, all that hit tests on the handles, etc..., but I am looking for a `C++` library that saves me from all that implementation.
I found something similar [here](https://www.devdept.com/support/samples) (see DraftingDemo), but it is `WPF` only.
Before trying [to host](https://github.com/Microsoft/WPF-Samples/tree/master/Migration%20and%20Interoperability/Win32HostingWPFPage) `WPF` content in `Win32` (that I would avoid), I would like to know if there is some library `Direct2D` (with `MFC` or not) for that.

Comment: Library recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: Maybe [SFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org/)?

Comment: [Direct2D Transforms Overview - Geometry Transforms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Direct2D/direct2d-transforms-overview#geometry-transforms)